# how to query object in mongo using prisma

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, prisma

I want to query by using where in object with prisma and mongo
Here is my prisma schema

```
model Member {
  id                 String               @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  bank    BankInfo
  @@map("members")
}

type BankInfo {
  bankNo   String
}

 const member = await this.prisma.member.findFirst({
      where: { bank: { bankNo: 'test' } },
 });
```

I got an error
Error:
Invalid `prisma.member.findFirst()` invocation:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use equal operator ($eq) like that :

```
const member = await this.db.member.find({
    bank: { $eq: { bankNo: 'test' } }
})
```